# Array multiplication in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, matrix-multiplication, vba

In my excel document I have two sheets. The first is a data set and the second is a matrix of the relationship between two of the variables in my data set. Each possibility of the variable is a column in my matrix. I'm trying to get the sum of the products of the elements in two different arrays. Right now I'm using the formula `{=SUM(N3:N20 * F3:F20)}` and manually changing the columns each time. But my data set is over 800 items...

Ideally I'd like to know how to write a program that reads the value of the variable in my dataset looks up the correct columns in the matrix, multiplies them together, sums the products, and puts the result in the correct place in my data set. However, just knowing the result for all the possible combinations of columns would also save me alot of time. Its an 18x18 matrix. Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: `Ideally I'd like to know how to write a program` I guess this means you want to explore `VBA`? I added the `excel-vba Tag` then for you get the right help that you need. It would also help if you can post sample data and expected result to help us visualize what you want.

Comment: better if you share your dataset sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little bit ambiguous *but* as far as i understand your question you want to multiply different sets of two columns in the same sheet and put their result into the next sheet, is it so? if so, please post `images of your work (all sheets)`. Your answer is possible even in Excel only without any vba code, thanks.
you can also use `=SUMPRODUCT(N3:N20,F3:F20)` for your formula instead of {=SUM(N3:N20 * F3:F20)}